# How can i add product Accessories from front-end using custom php form?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks, child-theme

I have a custom HTML form I am saving the product data using WordPress-Woocommerce functions.

I am able to save all the product details but getting issue in saving Product Accessories ( please check the attached screenshot )

[image: Product Accessores Oprtion]

[image: Add Product accessories option]

I have saved the product accessories in a serialized array format. Which might be not correct.

Is there any other way of saving the product accessories. Any Woocommerce Function/filter/hook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code have you used for this so far? only based on an image will not give you much response

Comment: I am serializing the product ids and saving it into the post_meta with key _accessory_ids

`update_post_meta( $post_id, '_accessory_ids', serialize( $_accessory_ids ) );`

Comment: With this code it is saving into key in this format.
`s:71:"a:5:{i:0;s:2:"70";i:1;s:2:"58";i:2;s:2:"46";i:3;s:2:"27";i:4;s:2:"24";}";`
But It should be in this format.
`a:2:{i:0;i:20;i:1;i:28;}`